# How to override supportsInterface() function if contract needs to support many interfaces?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, interfaces

I'm creating a basic ERC721 token that extends ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, AccessControlEnumerable.
I want it to support ERC721Enumerable and AccessControlEnumerable interfaces. Is it enough to call super.supportsInterface(interfaceId) in my overridden supportsInterface function to achieve it?

Also, I would like to know is there a list of interfaceIDs of well-known interfaces, e.g. IERC20, IERC721?

```
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, AccessControlEnumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code already overrides the `supportsInterface()` method well and will cause all the extended contract's methods to be called. This method is also used by the [OpenZeppelin Contracts Wizard](https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/).

If you get more interfaces, just add them in the `override()` tuple.

The order of the interfaces might be important as they get called from the last to the first.

```
function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view override(ERC721, AccessControl) returns (bool) {
  return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
}
```

For example, having this topology,

```
contract MyContract is ERC721, AccessControl {
  function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view override(ERC721, AccessControl) returns (bool) {
    return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
  }
}

contract ERC721 is ERC165, IERC721, IERC721Metadata {
  function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC165, IERC165) returns (bool) {
    return interfaceId == type(IERC721).interfaceId
        || interfaceId == type(IERC721Metadata).interfaceId
        || super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
  }
}

abstract contract AccessControl is IAccessControl, ERC165 {
  function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
    return interfaceId == type(IAccessControl).interfaceId
        || super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
  }
}
```

the functions get called in this order:

1. MyContract
2. AccessControl
3. ERC721
4. ERC165

---

As for the `interfaceId`s of known contracts, they are sometimes listed on the EIP page of the contract somewhere in the comments, just search for `0x`.
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721

Another approach to get the value of the interface is using REMIX IDE and calling a function like this.

```
  event Log(bytes4 data);

  function log() public {
    emit Log(type(IERC721).interfaceId);
  }
```

```
ERC165               0x01ffc9a7
ERC721               0x80ac58cd
ERC721Metadata       0x5b5e139f
ERC721TokenReceiver  0x150b7a02
ERC721Enumerable     0x780e9d63
AccessControl        0x7965db0b
```